# how to merge different files of code into one file code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I have  four files of php code inside my folder, but i want to merge it together into just one file of code. Please, i need an help. Here are the codes below;

```
**index.php**
<?php
  include_once('connect.php');
  $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM p_r_customers ORDER BY prc_id ASC");
  $result->execute();
?>
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" aligh= "center" >
        <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
        ?>
        <tr class="record">
            <td><?php echo $row['prc_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['prc_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['prc_email']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['prc_phone']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="editform.php?id=<?php echo $row['prc_id']; ?>"> Edit </a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            }
       ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>

**editform.php**

<?php
        include_once('connect.php');
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM p_r_customers WHERE prc_id= :userid");
        $result->bindParam(':userid', $id);
        $result->execute();
        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    ?>
    <form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['prc_name']; ?>" /><br>
    Email<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['prc_email']; ?>" /><br>
    Phone<br>
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $row['prc_phone']; ?>" /><br>
    Gender<br>
    <input type="text" name="gender" value="<?php echo $row['prc_gender']; ?>" /><br>
    Birthday Day<br>
    <input type="text" name="dob_day" value="<?php echo $row['prc_dob_day']; ?>" /><br>
    Birthday Month<br>
    <input type="text" name="dob_month" value="<?php echo $row['prc_dob_month']; ?>" /><br>
    Age group<br>
    <input type="text" name="age_group" value="<?php echo $row['prc_age_group']; ?>" /><br>
    Card ID<br>
    <input type="text" name="card" value="<?php echo $row['prc_card']; ?>" /><br>
    Password<br>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $row['prc_password']; ?>" /><br>
    Country<br>
    <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $row['prc_country']; ?>" /><br>
    State<br>
    <input type="text" name="state" value="<?php echo $row['prc_state']; ?>" /><br>
    Rand<br>
    <input type="text" name="rand" value="<?php echo $row['prc_rand']; ?>" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
    </form>
    <?php
        }
  ?>

**update.php**

<?php
include_once('connect.php');
include('editform.php');

if (isset($_POST[update])){
  $sql = "UPDATE p_r_customers
          SET prc_name='$_POST[name]', prc_email='$_POST[email]', prc_phone='$_POST[phone]',
           prc_gender='$_POST[gender]', prc_dob_day='$_POST[dob_day]', prc_dob_month='$_POST[dob_month]',
           prc_age_group='$_POST[age_group]', prc_card='$_POST[card]', prc_password='$_POST[password]',
           prc_country='$_POST[country]', prc_state='$_POST[state]', prc_rand='$_POST[rand]'
          WHERE prc_id='$_POST[id]'";

$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[phone]',
 '$_POST[gender]', '$_POST[dob_day]', '$_POST[dob_month]',
 '$_POST[age_group]', '$_POST[card]', '$_POST[password]',
 '$_POST[country]', '$_POST[state]', '$_POST[rand]'));
header("location: index.php");
}
?>

**connect.php**

    <?php
    $db_host        = 'localhost';
    $db_user        = 'root';
    $db_pass        = '';
    $db_database    = 'aziz';

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_database, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    ?>
```

I have four files of php code inside my folder, but i want to merge it together into just one file of code. The codes is shown above.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Thank you collinD. What should i do the the <a href="editform.php?  and <form action="update.php"

Answer (score 3):

If you need to write all code in one page than you must create database connection on the top of `index.php` some changes from your code.

1. copy the complete code in index.php
2. Remove `include_once('connect.php');` and write code on the top of index.
3. change this line as `<form action="index" method="post">`
4. change this line as `<td><a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $row['prc_id']; ?>"> Edit </a></td>`.
5. create functions for connection,form data and showing data on page.

Comment: Nawaz, Thank you. How do i create functions for connection,form data and showing data on page. Please guide me

Comment: simple create `function connection(){}` put your connection code in the curly brackets. don't forget to return the connection. similarly create other methods.

Comment: if your problem is solved please upvote the answer thanx.